# VBA Data validation first selection

Tags: vba, list, validation, excel

I have a list of dates from A2 to A200

I have in Cell B1 validation list that refers to A2:A200 and it works fine.

But when i want to select a date from the list it always gives the value from A2 first ...

Is there a way in VBA to assign it the value of A100 to be first ?

Answer (score 2):

***Without VBA:***

In **C2** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,199-ROWS($1:1),0)
```

and copy down.  Then use **C2:C200** as the validation list.

***With VBA***:

try this macro:

```
Sub InternalString()
    Dim s As String

    s = Range("A200").Value
    For i = 199 To 2 Step -1
      s = s & "," & Cells(i, "A").Value
    Next i

    Range("B1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=s
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! thank you, but this solution only reverses the list ... what i would need is to still be able to read all the data (from A2 to A200) but the starting point, when i open the list should be the value from A100, i hope its more understandable.